# Fortran arrays in hybrid MPI/OpenMP

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmp, openmpi, intel-fortran

I am facing the following issue when running a hybrid MPI/OpenMP 
code with GNU and Intel compilers and OpenMPI. The code is big (commercial) 
written in Fortran. It compiles and runs fine with GNU compilers
but crashes with Intel compilers.

I have monitored the part of the code when the program stops working,
it has the following structure:

```
subroutine test(n,dy,dy)
integer :: i
integer, parameter :: n=6
real*8 :: dx(num),dy(num), ener

ener=0.0
!$omp parallel num_threads(2)
!$omp do 
  do i=1,100
  ener = ener + funct(n,dx,dy) + i
  enddo 
!$omp end do
!$omp end parallel

end subroutine test
```

and the function funct has this structure:

```
real*8 function funct(n,dx,dy)
integer :: n
real*8 :: dx(*),dy(*)
funct = 0.0
do i=1,n
    funct = funct + dx(i)+dy(i)
enddo
end function funct
```

Specifically the code stops inside `funct` (with Intel). The
program is able to get the end of `funct` but only one thread
of the two requested is able to return the value, I checked
that by printing the thread numbers.

This issue is only for Intel compilers, for GNU I don't get
the issue.

One way to avoid the issue, I found, is by using plain arrays
inside `funct` as follows:

```
real*8 function funct(n,dx,dy)
integer :: n
real*8 :: dx(n),dy(n)
```

but my point is that I don't understand what is happening. 
My guess is that in the Intel case, the compiler cannot 
figure out the length of `dx` and `dy` inside `funct` but I am 
not sure. I tried to reproduce this issue with a small 
Fortran program but I was not able to see that issue.

Any comment is welcome.

One update: I eliminated the issue with the race condition (this is
not the real problem, what I wrote here was the structure of the code).

I realized that subroutine`test` is being called from another subroutine
`upper` which defines dx,dy as pointers:

```
subroutine upper
real*8,save,pointer :: dx(:)=>Null(), dy(:)=>Null()
....
call test(n,dx,dy)
...
end subroutine upper
```

what I did now, was to replace pointers by allocatables:

```
subroutine upper
real*8,save,dimension(:),allocatable :: dx,dy
....
allocate(dx(n),dy(n))
call test(n,dx,dy)
...
end subroutine upper
```

and I don't get the issue with Intel. I don't know what could be the
difference between pointers and allocatables.

Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a complete (but minimal) example for us to look at?  See, for example, [mcve].

Comment: Do you mean to have a reduction clause on that OpenMP parallel do?  Also, you mention it's a hybrid MPI/OpenMP program, but beyond that you mention nothing related to MPI: how important is the MPI aspect?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried a simple code where I have a main program and a function funct as given above. However, when I compiled it with OpenMP it doesn't show the issue. As I mentioned, this is just the part of the code where the program stops. Program is parallelized with MPI, so that each MPI sees the parallel region and generates the two threads. num variable is supposed to be n, sorry.

Comment: I went ahead and did the change myself. I think the fortran tag is much more important than multithreading which is implied by openmp. Feel free to change it to a different comination.

Comment: Please submit this to Intel premier support. You can submit customer confidential information (i.e. code) there.

Comment: There's a huge race here; each iteration of the loop in subroutine test writes the whole of the dx and dy arrays (admittedly with the same values each time!). And, what do you mean by "the code stops", does it crash? Are you sure you have enough available stack? How big is "num" (or "n")?

Comment: Could you construct a complete small program which has the problem and which we can test on our computer?